# Are the Ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 and ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 strong?

Tags: security, encryption, tls1.2

As part of security improvements I have disabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 in AWS Load balancer by selecting the below SSL security policy.

```
   ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06
```

Once this policy is updated the server has listed below Ciphers which are supported.

```
Preferred TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256  Curve 25519 DHE 253
Preferred TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve 25519 DHE 253
```

Are these Ciphers strong or safe?
As per my understanding from web, the GCM ones are strong Ciphers. However when I checked for others, say "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256" the search results only show "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256". Looks like this one has vulnerabilities (Beast attack). Are these both same? Is it ok to allow "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256" and "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"

Please advise.

Comment: Use AES-256, [prefer Chaha20](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70894/18298) if not restricted to AES and hardware performance. Forget TLS 1.2 and look in to TLS 1.3 ciphers suites where only [5 is listed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95611/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka That of course is true (and I'd not argue with you on cryptography anyway :) ), but client support is the obvious tradeoff. If the target is only modern browsers on recent OSes, then sure. It gets tricky when the target is broader.

Comment: As @GaborLengyel stated, we need support for both TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. Given this, please advise on the Ciphers mentioned in the question. Thanks

Comment: Forget about [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52566/18298) it leads many attacks.

Comment: Those are ill openSLL names; https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384/